# Windows azure cloud development

Tags: azure, cloud, cloud-hosting

I am new to cloud computing. I created a new cloud solution using Visual Studio 2010.
I need to deploy my solution somewhere in order to test it.
As I saw in my researches, I should have an account on http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/account/

Currently i do not have an account there, so where should I deploy my application, and how can i test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsazure/cc974146.aspx you can download the whole SDK and other tools which essentially allows you to run Azure on your local machine. It requires you to have SQL Server installed.

Apologies for the lack of details, it's quite a while since I did it myself. But, poke around on that page and you'll find all the tools and documenation you need. It's a big, hairy thing to get your head around so you'll need to set some time aside to just read, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Best resource to get started is the Azure training kit, get it here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=413e88f8-5966-4a83-b309-53b7b77edf78&displaylang=en

Watch some videos then dive into the labs, the best teacher is hands on experience.